# Is there any significance to the difference in Godzilla's roar?

Tags: analysis, sound-effects, monsterverse, godzilla-2014

As soon (or late, for that matter) as [*Godzilla*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0831387/) appears in full size in Hollywood's 2014 take on it, he utters a giant roar that seems to a large degree similar to his original roar from the Japanese movies finished with a very deep growling sound (that is also significantly featured in the trailer). And exactly this growling finish to his roar seems to add much to his gigantic presence and the awe-inspiring (for lack of a better term) atmosphere that accompanies him.

But at the end, when the supposedly dead *Godzilla* rises from the ashes of San Francisco and ventures into the ocean, effectively celebrated by the people (and the movie) for saving them (even if not their city ;-)) from the *MUTOs*, it is exactly this growling finish that I missed in his final "farewell roar". Now I certainly know that I'm absolutely splitting hairs here, but **is there any significance to the fact that his last roar didn't feature this "growling finish"** or is this a mere coincidence or mishearing on my part?

Comment: I nearly feel tempted to add the `dialogue` tag. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

My take on the final roar is it is a farewell to the people of San Francisco, where as the ones at the beginning were more of an attack roar. He's a little ticked the MUTO's have forced him to come calling, so the attack roar. When he's leaving he just can't go away, so says goodbye.

Comment: Hmm, this answer ventures quite deep into *Godzilla*'s characterization as a guardian of natural balance and the questions about his motivations and level of awareness of himself and his environment (which isn't a bad thing, though, and might make for an interesting question on its own, I guess).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson remember when Godzilla comes into San Francisco Bay. He is steaming in where the boats are blocking his way. He stops and tries to avoid them, in fact throughout the movie he tries to avoid hurting humans, but he does what he has to do, causing a lot of damage in the process, but nothing which he cannot avoid. His goal is to bring balance, which he does. I believe his intelligence and self-awareness are quite high. I liked the movie quite a bit, BTW.

Comment: Well, I also thought especially his eye-to-eye scene with *Ford* seemed to intend some actual understanding of us humans and our motives, but being not too acquainted with the originals, his nature and motivations seem rather unclear to me, even if *Dr. Serizawa* seems to characterize him out of nowhere. And yeah, I liked and enjoyed it very much, too.

Comment: Meh, [done](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/19555/49), better now when I've got a run than never. ;-)